# How to set a parameter default value to be a pure function of another parameter value?

Tags: scala, class, default-value

Say we want to define a case class `A` of 3 integer parameters: `b`, `c` and `d`. `b` and `c` must be specified, `d` is to be specified or considered equal to `c + 1` by default.

I would define this as follows:

```
case class A(b: Int, c: Int, d = c + 1)
```

But this doesn't work. What is the correct form?

As far as I can remember this is possible in Scala but I can't remember how can this be done.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible in Scala. One option would be to define an `apply` for `A` in its companion object that takes two parameters and gives the defaults to the last value.

Comment: @JSchlather that's it. Submit this as an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: @JSchlather It is possible, just not that useful for case classes specifically.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Hm, I see I was trying to curry the parenthesis as well, couldn't get it to work. You have to mark it as val to get it to work. Do you have any insight into why this is?

Comment: @JSchlather It works without `val`, but it's just a normal constructor parameter: it can be used only inside the body of the class. Case classes only make the parameters in the first list `val` automatically.

Answer (score 3):

```
case class A(b: Int, c: Int)(val d: Int = c + 1)

A(1, 1)().d // 2
```

But! This is a good solution for methods and non-`case` classes. However, for case classes this nearly certainly doesn't do what you want, because the automatically generated methods (`equals`, `hashCode`, `apply`, and `unapply`) only care about the first parameter list. So for this case, follow @JSchlather's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to make an apply on a companion object that has the desired substitution.

```
case class A(b: Int, c:Int, d: Int)

object A {
   def apply(b: Int, c:Int): A = A(b, c, c + 1)
}
```